# How to run modified tests only?

Tags: java, git, android-studio, testing, intellij-idea

I have modified several files within which there are several modified tests (my VCS is git).

I would like to launch all of them and only them. How can I achieve this using IntelliJ-IDEA (Android Studio actually)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not yet implemented in IntelliJ IDEA, but there is already a feature request created, please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154039